# Confusion about variable scope in if block

Tags: c#, variables, scope

How come this code

```
if(...)
{
    string b = "Hello";
}
if(...)
{
    string b = "World";
}
```

is perfectly fine, while this

```
if(...)
{
    string b = "Hello";
}
if(...)
{
    string b = "World";
}

string b = "Foo";
```

is not?

It yields

> A local variable 'b' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'b', which is already **used in a parent or current scope** to denote something else.

(emphasis mine).

As far as I understand, `string b = "Foo"` is defined in **method scope**, so neither in the **same scope** as the `string b = "Hello";` in the `if`-block, which also is not a **parent scope**.

Moreover, since example (1) works perfectly, I figured that `if` blocks have their very own, **closed** scope (therefore no collision).

How come the `if` blocks don't have "closed" scopes in example (2) as well?

Comment: `since example (1) works perfectly, I figured that if blocks have their very own, closed scope` - actually they also have access to parent scope(s).

Comment: the method scope includes the if-block scope

Comment: Yes, `string b = "Foo"` is in the method scope. That means it's in scope *for the entire method*, not just from its point of declaration. Which is the parent scope for `string b = "Hello"`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you, that made it clear for me. The error is about the parent scope for `string b = "Hello"`, which makes sense. I thought it referred to the parent scope of `string b = "Foo"`, which would not make much sense.

Comment: For the **scope** the order of the declarations doesn´t matter. So all the declarations within a scope are considered, not only those that come after your current one. So it won´t matter if your `string b = "Foo"` would stand before or after the ifs.

Comment: Yeah, the error is reported on the `Hello` and `World` lines, not the `Foo` line.

Comment: @HimBromBeere thank you very much, this one is important as well. I had the misunderstanding that scopes were kind of "sequential", as in when the `if`-blocks are over, their scopes are "gone" as well.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever in fact IntelliSense shows this particular error only when hovering about `string b = "Foo"` - when hovering about the `Hello` and `World` lines, it shows `"A local or parameter 'b' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter"`. Nevertheless, I now do get it, mainly thanks to your explanation. Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, and hopefully you know the fix. If there's naming confusion, pick better names or split the method apart (or both).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering only the scopes your second code is equivalent to this one:

```
string b = "Foo";
if(...)
{
    string b = "Hello";
}
if(...)
{
    string b = "World";
}
```

Here you see that you really have to decarations for `b`, one in the outer scope and one in the inner. That means it doesn´t matter in which **order** your declarations occur. Furthermore a scope is never just limited to itself, but to all child-scopes also. So in your case the scope for `string b = "Foo"` (which seems to be method-scope) contains the **entire** method, thus also the scope of the if-blocks. The latter however don´t include the scope of the method.

In your first example on the other hand the variables only live within the inner scope.

Answer (score 2):

In example 1, `b` is scoped to the if statements, as you correctly recognised. So you cannot access its value outside the if statements as `b` is then out of scope. It is perfectly fine to declare therefore perfectly fine to declare a new variable with the same name in every if block.

In example 2, `b` is scoped to the method that contains the if blocks. The if blocks have access to all variables which have a larger scope, so in their scope there already exists a variable `b`. That is why you cannot declare a new variable `b` within the if statements.